# Why Symfony File Upload path always begins with /public folder when using getenv()?

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, public

This is my code:

.env file:

```
UPLOAD_PATH=".var/uploads/docs"
```

MyController.php

```
$destination = getenv('UPLOAD_PATH');
/** @var UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
$uploadedFile = $form['file']->getData();
dump($uploadedFile->move($destination, $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName()));
```

The dump output:

```
  pathname: "./var/uploads/docs/test.txt"
  realPath: "/var/www/html/public/var/uploads/docs/test.txt"
```

Actually my intention is to save it in **var** folder but it always ends up in public/var... every path I enter no matter how and what end up in public folder.

However when I try this it works fine:

```
$destination = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir').'/var/uploads/docs';
```

I want to use the first way with getenv and .env, is there any way to make it work and upload files to desired folder?

Comment: It could be, because you have a relative path. Have you tried making your .env value an absolute path? You can also use Symfony parameters, when you filter the env value with resolve (see doctrine’s DATABASE_URL for how to do this). So for example it could look like `UPLOAD_PATH=“%kernel.root_dir%/var/uploads”` instead. If that solves it, but you don’t want to do this, you should probably probably prepend the base path when you do the `move()` operation

Comment: Even though its a bit of a non-answer, I can also recommend using [Flysystem](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/) as an alternative approach. It is great library for abstracting filesystem paths and has the benefit that you can easily switch the path at any point to even other filesystems like FTP or AWS S3, which can be nice